# Display Top 10 Associates using SAS

Tags: sas, proc

I want to display Top 10 associates list based on district.
    If district number is same for 2 associates then it should rank by considering another variable sales.

If district and sales count also same for 2 associates then it should consider another variable while ranking.

For this scenario, will Proc rank work or is there another way to achieve this output?

Ex,

```
data input;
input assoc_nm dist_num sales_cnt sales_amt;
datalines;

raju 1 59 1000
kumar 1 59 1600    
ramya 3 54 6900    
lakshmi 2 65 9000
;    
run;
```

output should be as follows for dist_num=1,

```
assoc_nm sales_cnt sales_amt rank

kumar     59         1600     1
raju      59         1000     2
```

for dist_num=2,

```
lakshmi 2 65 9000 1
```

for dist_num=3

```
ramya 3 54 6900
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for each district, you want the top 10, ranked/ordered by sales_cnt, and within the same sales_cnt, by sales_amt.

```
PROC SORT DATA=input ;
  BY district sales_cnt sales_amt ;
RUN ;

DATA input2 ;
  SET input ;
  BY district sales_amt ;
  IF FIRST.district THEN rank=0 ;
  rank+1 ;
  IF rank LE 10 ;
RUN ;
```

Simply filter, using a WHERE statement, for whichever district value you want.

Comment: Thank You so Much..It is Working.. :)

Comment: I have created the list of top associated for week,month and year separately.